# Не могу подключить Bootstrap

Tags: php, bootstrap, mvc

Bootstrap подключается только по адресу `localhost/site/` , если вести `localhost/site/index/index` (это одна и та самая страница )то работать  уже не будет. Получатся что ищет bootstrap по адресу   `localhost/site/index/index/View/css/bootstrap.css` а он по адресу `localhost/site/View/css/bootstrap.css`.может я что-то не так делаю. Структура сайта mvc.Метод Рендер

```
    protected function render($templateName)
{

    ob_start();
    //динамический контент 
    $render = SITE_DIR . DS . 'View' . DS . $this->name . DS . $templateName . '.php';
    if ($render) {
        include ($render);
    }
    //дефолтный шаблон в нем я подключаю bootstrap
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    include SITE_DIR . DS . 'View' . DS . 'Layout' . DS .'default' . '.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно на странице где ты хочешь подключить bootstrap прописать глобальный путь `localhost/site/index/index/View/css/bootstrap.css`, но вместо localhost напиши как оно у тебя на компе хранится.Это первый вариант, а второй это это локально прописать в index.html прописать путь к `/View/css/bootstrap.css`.

Comment: у меня же есть дефолтный шаблон и я в нем подключил bootstrap .этот дефолный шаблон каждый раз дефолно поключается.